# Why my code for inplace merge runs slower than std:: inplace_merge?

Tags: c++, merge, in-place

```
void bmerge(vecitr itr1, vecitr itr2, vecitr itr3)
{
    int s1 = itr2-itr1;  //both array are contiguous. itr1 is beggining of first arry
    int s2 =  itr3-itr2; // itr2 is beginning of 2nd array and itr3 is end of 2nd array
    int i=0,j=0;
    vector<int> buffer(s1);
    copy(itr1,itr2,buffer.begin()); //copying content of 1st array to a buffer
    vecitr temp = buffer.begin();

    while(i<s1 && j<s2)
    {
        if(*(temp+i) < *(itr2+j))
        {

                *(itr1+k) = *(temp+i);
                i++;
                k++;
        }
        else
        {
                *(itr1+k) = *(itr2+j);
                j++;
                k++;

            }

    }
     if(i<s1)
        {
            copy(temp+i,temp+s1,itr1+k);

        }

}
```

This code runs like 3 time slower than std::inplace_merge. I just don't understand why. I have a vector of around 100,000 iterators which points to sorted sequence in a single vector and I call this function to merge them recursively into 1 single sequence.

Comment: Did you profile your function?

Comment: 1) What compiler options did you use to build your program?  Are you building with optimizations turned on?  2) Why do you believe your code can "beat" or match the standard library's version, written by some of the best programmers in the business?

Comment: yes, I mean the point at which I was calling inplace_merge, I am now calling this function and run time doubled.

Comment: The source to `std::inplace_merge` is available in your header files, so you can just compare the implementations. Yours is O(n log n) due to the call to `upper_bound`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I used inline if that could do anything. plus I want to know those optimization. I mean it's just merging what could be different? Moreover, I looked at some details of std::inplace _merge and I don't think I does something very inefficient.

Comment: @agenius5 `inline` is not an optimization setting.  What are the compiler options you used to build your application?  Any question regarding the speed of code requires you to post what compiler options you used, especially the ones that turn on optimizations -- otherwise the timing information is meaningless.

Comment: I was using galloping from timsort.  I too thought that it is bottleneck so I removed it as you can see now but same result.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie, it's g++ compiler. I installed it with MinGw

Comment: Again, what compiler options did you use?  Did you use the `-O2` or `-O3` option when compiling your code?  If you used `-O0` or no option, then your timing information is meaningless.

Comment: Okay, Sorry I have no idea about all that. Let me look at what all those options are and compile with them. Right now I don't use any such options.